# ¿Cómo puedo refrescar los datos para que se refleje el cambio en el siguiente escenario SQL Server y VB.NET?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

Verán, simplemente creo un inicio de sesión con el siguiente bloque:

```
 Using c As New SqlConnection(Conexion(cServidor, True,, True))

    c.Open()

    ComandoCrearSQL = New SqlCommand("CREATE Login [" & MiInicio & "] WITH PASSWORD=N''", c)

    ComandoCrearSQL.ExecuteNonQuery()

 End Using
```

Se crea, pero mientras el programa está en ejecución no se refleja el cambio, porque no pudo usar el inicio de sesión recién creado. Pero si cierro el programa y lo vuelvo ejecutar allí sí lo usa correctamente. Me parece que es una cuestión de refrescar los datos, pero ¿cómo?